# Quote-like environment with vertical bar, across pages

Tags: environments, page-breaking

The following LaTeX code creates a quote-like environment ("answer") that has a vertical bar to the left. How can the environment be redefined so that it flows across page breaks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[height=4in]{geometry} % keep pages small for demo

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\mydepth}
\newlength{\myheight}
\newenvironment{answer}%
{\vspace*{3pt}\par\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\quad\begin{minipage}{.89\linewidth}\color{black}\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}\vspace*{-.7\baselineskip}}%
{\vspace*{.3\baselineskip}\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
\settodepth{\mydepth}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
\settoheight{\myheight}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
\addtolength{\myheight}{\mydepth}%
\noindent\makebox[0pt]{%
  \color{black}\hspace{-0pt}\rule[-\mydepth]{1pt}{\myheight}}%
  \usebox{\mybox}%
  \vspace*{3pt}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[2-3]
  \end{answer}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at the `changebar` package, which does what you want out of the box, I think.

Comment: The `changebar` package works perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion, @AlanMunn!

Answer (score 3):

The `changebar` package indeed provides the needed solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xcolor,leftbars]{changebar}
\usepackage[height=3in]{geometry}

\cbcolor{red}
\newenvironment{answer}%
{\begin{quote}%
  \begin{changebar}\cbcolor{gray}\color{black}}%
  {\end{changebar}%
\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\

\begin{answer}
  \lipsum[2-3]
\end{answer}

\end{document}
```